# Paypal sendbox business account zip code not US

Tags: paypal

I trying to register an Italian business account in paypal developer page.
I would like to enter a italian zip code for test functionality but I can't. Can I create a business account only American to make my tests? Thanks.

Comment: I was able to create Spain based accounts but none of them would accept payments so I ended up using US accounts for all my development. I'm a total newbie though so not sure if that's how it's supposed to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an account via www.paypal.com and use that account to login on https://developer.paypal.com/

Comment: Let me resume, for development I need to create the Business User Account, but with NON-US address, zip code and state ?